# Não foi possível instalar o pacote 'Npgsql 4.1.2'. aplicação .NET Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql

Estou tentando instalar o package do `Npgsql` para consumir os dados do PostgreSQL no meu projeto , mas me retorna o erro abaixo:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Could not install package 'Npgsql 4.1.2'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Eu entendo o erro, mas não sei como tratar. Pesquinsando na internet vi algo relacionado a [Multi-targeting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks) mas naõ compreendi muito bem como adaptar no meu projeto e/ou se isso é "seguro" em fazer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse erro corre quando o pacote tem uma dependência de uma versão específica do .NET Framework na qual o seu projeto não possui.

Seu projeto está na versão 4.5.2 e segundo o pacote no site do [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/), na opção "Dependencies", o seu projeto precisa estar na versão 4.6.1.

Você tem duas opções, dependendo do que ver viável para você:

1 - Alterar a sua versão do projeto para a versão 4.6.1 ou mais recente, navegando até as propriedades do seu projeto, e em application "Target Framework", mude para uma versão atual.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas atenção, verifique se você realmente pode efetuar essa alteração e se não irá quebrar nada do seu projeto devido a mudança.

2 - Instalar uma versão mais antiga do pacote.

Segundo o site do pacote do Nuget, a versão 4.0.10 precisará de no mínimo da versão 4.5.1, no qual você poderá instalar em seu projeto sem modificar o framework usado.

Contudo, por ser uma versão mais antiga do pacote, pode não conter as últimas melhorias e estar desatualizado com as mais novas atualizações.

Você pode encontrar esta versão [aqui](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/4.0.10).